# Perforce unicode issue: sync files with non-ascii characters leads to a truncation

Tags: unicode, cmd, perforce

I am using `P4/NTX64/2016.2/1487173 (2017/02/14)` and `Windows 7 64bit (Code Page is 936)`. My server is working in uniocde mode and the charset server uses is `utf8-no-bom`.

When I excuted commands below in the CMD, instead of the file `//Depot/副本.txt`, `p4` synced all of the files in my depot.

> p4 sync -f "//Depot/副本.txt"

I have tried to add `-C utf8`, `-C auto` and `-Q utf8`, but `p4` seems to truncate `//Depot/副本.txt` which results in a full depot sync like below:

> p4 sync -f

Only adding `-C cp936` can solve this problem(Actually, [this option](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/P4CHARSET.html) only controls behavior of unicode type file translation):

> p4 -C cp936 sync -f "//Depot/副本.txt"

However, this workaround fails when translating unicode type files.

I know that Windows CMD needs `cp936 encoded characters`. Is this some sort of bug of perforce command line tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `P4COMMANDCHARSET` to `cp936` -- that will tell the CLI to use that charset for translating arguments, but not for translating file content.

e.g.:

```
p4 -Q cp936 sync -f "//Depot/副本.txt"
```

or:

```
p4 set P4COMMANDCHARSET=cp936
p4 sync -f "//Depot/副本.txt"
```

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/P4COMMANDCHARSET.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. In Windows of Chinese version, CMD uses cp936 as the default code page.

Comment: If (and only if) P4CHARSET is set for the client, the server
must also be operating in Unicode mode.  This mode is switched
on (and never off) by invoking 'p4d -xi' on the server.  This
operation verifies that all existing metadata is valid UTF8,
and then sets the protected counter 'unicode' to indicate that
the server now runs in Unicode mode.